# Exploiting RSA to access remote computer

Tags: ssh, security, rsa

as part of an exercise I am supposed to exploit RSA in a way so that I can connect to a remote machine without knowing the password. To accomplish this I have been given a bunch of private and public keys.

If I try to connect using ssh -i someprivatekey jonas@192.168.178.31 then I am still asked to give the password. How can I bypass the authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass the password authentification by providing the correct private key in your ssh call i.e. a private key matching one of the public keys stored in the target's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.